# How to reset CountDownTimer without having to pause first

Tags: java, countdowntimer

Novice looking for some help~

I have a CountDownTimer with start, pause, and reset buttons. When the timer is running, I'd like to be able to hit the reset button to restart it from the original value (edittext.) Currently, the only way I am able to accomplish this is to hit "pause" then "reset."

To give an example of what I'm hoping to accomplish:

If timer is set to 10s,
10-9-8-reset-10-9-8-7-6-5-reset-10-9....

Thanks in advance!

I've looked through the forums and android dev site

EDIT: Original problem solved but another has arisen. Code below shows changes made. If I hit start-pause-start too quickly, one second is added to the original countdown time. For example: 15-14-pause-start-15-pause-start-16-pause-start-17-pause-start-18

```
private void pauseTimer(boolean actualPause) {
            mCountdowntimer.cancel();
            mTimerRunning = false;
            if(actualPause)
                updateWatchInterface();
        }

        private void resetTimer() {
            if(mTimerRunning)
                pauseTimer(false);
            mTimeLeftInMillis = mStartTimeInMillis;
            updateCountDownText();
            updateWatchInterface();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your exact problem is, so I will mention a couple of approaches.

Option 1: If you don't have any problems remembering the 'start time' (that's what mStartTimeInMillis denotes, right?), then you can simply change the signature of the function pauseTimer as follows:

```
private void pauseTimer(boolean actualPause) {
            mCountdowntimer.cancel();
            mTimerRunning = false;
            if(actualPause)
                updateWatchInterface();
        }

        private void resetTimer() {
            if(mTimerRunning)
                pauseTimer(false);
            mTimeLeftInMillis = mStartTimeInMillis;
            updateCountDownText();
            updateWatchInterface();
        }
```

Also modify the top portion as:

```
public void onClick(android.view.View view) {
                    if (mTimerRunning) {
                        pauseTimer(true);
                        }
    //...Other code
}
```

This will ensure that the watch interface is *not updated* to show the paused interface when you press the reset button, but the actual working would be as if you had pressed pause first and then reset. Also, we put a check to ensure that the pause timer is not called if it was actually *pause followed by reset*.

Option 2: If you can't get the reference to mStartTimeInMillis without calling pause first, you can use SharedPreferences, and save the start time every time you start the timer, thus allowing you access to the variable as follows:

```
//Put
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("time", *Your_value* );
editor.apply();

//Get
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String name = prefs.getString("time", "00:00");//"00:00" is the default value if the //entry doesn't exist.
```

I hope these will be helpful :)

Comment: Hi @Aditya,  Thanks for answering!
I made the changes you listed. When I hit "reset," the time goes back to the original value but stays there. If I want it to count down again, I must hit start (e.g. 15-14-13-12-reset button hit - start button hit - 15-14-13)
Here's what I'm hoping to accomplish: Say I set the timer to 15s. If the timer is counting down and I hit the "reset" button, I want the timer to go back to 15s AND start counting down again on its own. I want the reset button to both reset the time and restart the timer all on one click, like this (15-14-13-12-reset button hit -15-14)

Comment: You can handle this by simply adding a call to the startTimer() function at the end of the resetTimer() function, much like adding a  call to stopTimer() at the start. Also, in case you don't want the countdown to happen automatically if the reset is hit when the timer is not running, you can handle it with a boolean just like in case of pauseTimer().
But I suspect your job will be handled by simply adding a call to startTimer() at the end of resetTimer().

Comment: Ok so one problem left I'm hoping to fix. If I hit start-pause-start too quickly, one second is added to the original countdown time. For example: 15-14-pause-start-15-pause-start-16-pause-start-17-pause-start-18. Any ideas what might be causing this?